# TableView Cell Not Updating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to update the labels in a custom cell based on a struct's bool property, however it only seems to update once.

When a new object in the array is created, I set it to false.  When the property is later set to true, the cell updates appropriately.  When I set it back to false, the cell doesn't change.  Print statements within the logic show that the conditions are being met correctly for either, so I don't see why the cell wouldn't "change back".
Thanks!

```
struct Meal: Codable {
    var name: String
    var arrayOfDishes: [Dish]
}

struct Dish: Codable {
    var name: String
    var isActive: Bool
    var arrayOfSteps: [Step]
}

//inside cellForRowAt (I have multiple tableViews within one VC)

case mealTableView:

                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomMealCell", for: indexPath)
                    as! MealTableViewCell

                    if meal.arrayOfDishes.isEmpty {
                        cell.mealName.text = ""
                        return cell
                    } else {
                        if meal.arrayOfDishes[indexPath.row].isActive == true {
                            cell.mealName.text = meal.arrayOfDishes[indexPath.row].name
                            return cell
                        } else if meal.arrayOfDishes[indexPath.row].isActive == false {
                            return cell
                        }
                    return cell
            }
```

Button press that changes the bool: (sender.tag is from another tableView, but works correctly)

```
@objc func onClickedDishBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    if meal.arrayOfDishes[sender.tag].isActive == false {
        meal.arrayOfDishes[sender.tag].isActive = true
    } else if meal.arrayOfDishes[sender.tag].isActive == true {
        meal.arrayOfDishes[sender.tag].isActive = false
    }

    mealTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Cells are reused.  You don't do anything to the cell in the case where `isActive` is false, so the cell will retain its previous values.  Also, reloading the whole tableview is unnecessary; you are better just reloading the affected row.  You can use `.toggle` to toggle a boolean.  Using the `tag` property can also cause problems if the cells are re-ordered.

Comment: @Paulw11 Interesting; thanks for the input.  What would be the best way to not return anything if false then?

Comment: What do you want to have if it is false? A blank `mealName` - No cell at all?  It isn't clear what your desired behaviour is.

Comment: No cell at all.  I built this concept previously using two arrays, an "active" array and "potential" array, and the mealTableView in question would simply populate with the "active" array.  It proved to be too cumbersome, however, so I'm trying to get this bool property method to work instead.  So if the bool is true, the meal is seen in the cell, if false, it does not appear.

Comment: Your first approach was right; You will always have the number of rows returned by `numberOfRows`.  You can clear the name text, but you can't not have a row based on the value being `false`

Comment: Would it work to have numberOfRows do a check for how many in the array are true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202612/discussion-between-paulw11-and-moosgrn).

Comment: you can use protocols to send stage change from the cell to the tableView controller.